# Writing a text file c++

Tags: c++

This is my header file Person.hpp:

```
#ifndef PERSON_HPP
#define PERSON_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Person {
public:
    Person(string name_val = "", int id_val = 0);
    virtual void write(ostream& strm);
    virtual void read(istream& strm);
private:
    string name;
    int id;
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& strm, Person& person);
istream& operator>>(istream& strm, Person& person);

Person::Person(string name_val, int id_val)
: name(name_val), id(id_val) {

}

void Person::write(ostream& strm) {
    strm << id << " " << name;
}

void Person::read(istream& strm) {
    strm >> id >> name;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& strm, Person& person) {
    person.write(strm);
    return strm;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& strm, Person& person) {
    person.read(strm);
    return strm;
}

#endif
```

and second header file from the first one Student.hpp:

```
#ifndef STUDENT_HPP
#define STUDENT_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include "Person.hpp"
using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
    Student(string name_val = "", int id_val = 0, double gpa_val = 0.0);
    void write(ostream& strm);
    void read(istream& strm);
private:
    double gpa;
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& strm, Student& student);
istream& operator>>(istream& strm, Student& student);

Student::Student(string name_val, int id_val, double gpa_val)
: gpa(gpa_val) {

}

void Student::write(ostream& strm) {
    //wait for modify
}

void Student::read(istream& strm) {
    //wait for modify too.
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& strm, Student& student) {
    student.write(strm);
    return strm;
}

istream& operator>>(istream& strm, Student& student) {
    student.read(strm);
    return strm;
}

#endif
```

and main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Person.hpp"
#include "Student.hpp"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    Student aStudent;

    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("Student.txt");

    cout << "Enter ID and name, and grade point average" << endl;
    while (cin >> aStudent) {
        outFile << aStudent << endl;
        cout << "Enter ID and name, and grade point average" << endl;
    }
    outFile.close();
}
```

I want to collect my data like this:

```
Enter ID and name, and grade point average
5601 Bird 3.01
Enter ID and name, and grade point average
5602 Bee 2.58
Enter ID and name, and grade point average
5603 Bow 4.00
Enter ID and name, and grade point average
^Z (terminates)
```

And the program will create the text file name student.txt
and collect ID and name and GPA in this text file. (Sorry for a long code.)

How do I Modify Student.hpp?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. You first read/write the base class (`Person`) and then read/write `Student`-specific data:

```
void Student::write(ostream& strm) {
    Person::write(strm);
    strm << gpa;
}

void Student::read(istream& strm) {
    Person::read(strm);
    strm >> gpa;
}
```

That being said, this could be in `operator<<` and `operator>>`, no `read`/`write` functions needed (unless you want them). Also, start using the `const` keyword, e.g.:

```
write(ostream& strm) const;
//                   ^^^^^

ostream& operator<<(ostream& strm, Student const& student);
//                                         ^^^^^
```

Comment: I got error a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Comment: @Araya Where exactly?

Comment: `void Student::write(ostream& strm) {
    Person::write(strm);  //this line
    strm << gpa;
}

void Student::read(istream& strm) {
    Person::read(strm); //this line
    strm >> gpa;
}`

Comment: Well, you didn't make `Student` inherit `Person`. And don't forget to construct it properly in `Student`'s constructor.

Comment: You should probably know.

Comment: I have collect
5603 Bow 4
but I want to collect
5603 Bow 4.00

Comment: Then treat 4.00 as string not as number